# Quick Q - Can't Write to File the Output of a Function

Tags: c++, function, ofstream

[Code](https://gist.github.com/41cafb1a0b3cb2e86db2):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

void printVector (const vector<string>& theVect, vector<bool>& bArray, int nItems){
    for (int i = 0; i < nItems; ++i)
       if (bArray[i] == true)
         cout << theVect[i] << " ";
         outFile << theVect[i];
    cout << "\n";
    outFile << "\n";
}

void nCombination(const vector<string> &Vect,int n, int r){

    vector<bool> myBits(n, false);  // everything is false now
    int count = 1; 
    for (size_t i = n-1; i >= 0 && count <= r; --i, ++count){
        myBits[i] = true;
    }
    do  // start combination generator
    {
       printVector(Vect, myBits, n );
    } while (next_permutation(myBits.begin(), myBits.end()));;  // change the bit pattern
}

void nPermutation(vector<string> o, int r){
    do {
        for(int count = 0; count < r; count++){
        cout << o[count] << " " ;
        outFile << o[count] << " ";
    }
        cout<< endl;
        outFile << endl;
    } 
    while (next_permutation(o.begin(), o.end()));
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

int numofOps;
char Op;
int n;
int r;
string line;

    ifstream myFile("infile.dat");
    myFile >> numofOps;
    myFile.ignore(1,'\n');

    ofstream outFile;
    outFile.open ("example.txt");

    for(int q = 0; q < numofOps; ++q){
    myFile.get(Op);
    myFile >> n;
    myFile>> r;

    vector<string> original(n);
    for(int i = 0;i <= n - 1; i++){
        myFile.ignore(1,'\n');
        myFile >> original[i];}

    myFile.ignore(1,'\n');

    sort(original.begin(), original.end());

    cout<< '\n'<< endl;


    if(Op == 'P'){
        nPermutation(original, r);
    }
    else{
        if(Op == 'C')
            nCombination(original,n,r);
        else
            cout << "Incorrect Input" << endl;
    }
    original.clear();
    }
    outFile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

My code works but when I add in the outFile to write everything to a file called example, it doesn't work.  How can I print out the result of the functions??

Examples would be so nice!!

Comment: You can't access `outFile` from another function because it's locally scoped to `main`. Either pass it along as another parameter or make `outFile` global -- the latter is less preferable.

Comment: Even if I make it global, it compiles but nothing gets written into the file? Any help??

Answer (score 1):

One immediate problem springing to mind:

```
if (bArray[i] == true)
     cout << theVect[i] << " ";
     outFile << theVect[i];
```

Python is the only language I'm aware of that uses indentation to control blocking of statements. In C-based languages, you should use braces:

```
if (bArray[i] == true) {
     cout << theVect[i] << " ";
     outFile << theVect[i];
}
```

---

On top of that, the code you've given shouldn't even compile. You create `outFile` as a *local* parameter inside `main()` then attempt to use it in the other functions, where it's not accessible.

You should either make it "global" by moving it out of `main()` so that every function can see it (unwise, but probably the quickest solution here) or pass it as a parameter to each function that needs to use it.

For the former, you could use:

```
using namespace std;
ofstream outFile;     // taken from main().
```

For the latter, it's a matter of adding it for each call to `printVector()`, `nCombination()` and `nPermutation()`, and modifying those functions so that they accept it, for example:

```
void nPermutation (
    vector<string> o,
    int            r,
    ofstream       os
) {
    os << "blah blah blah\n";
}
:
nPermutation (original, r, outFile);
```

Comment: Even if I make it global, it compiles but nothing gets written into the file?  Any help??

Comment: did you remember to still open it, in main?

Comment: open it within the function?

Comment: @Not_NSA_I_Swear, no, still open it it main. You may want to check `outFile.fail()` to see if there was a problem opening the file. And make sure you've _moved_ the declaration from `main` to global area, not _copied_ it. Otherwise, you open the main local one and try to use the unopened global one in the other functions.